# Vue JS rendering

Tags: vue.js

I was taught to make requests to my API via axios, to retrieve the data in a client-side container and to dispatch the content in the template of my component.
It works quite well.
Having already used twig, I wonder if there would be a possibility to render directly from the server (nodejs) for my part to the client (Vue) (for example for static data) with a method of type render.
Well I guess in production it's not feasible.

CLient side ( VueJs3 ) Axios request

```js
submit(){
        let self = this;
      
        if (this.$refs.form.validate()){

         
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData = {
            name : this.name,
            surname : this.surname,
            email : this.email,
            question : this.question,
            agree : this.agree
          }
          axios.post(this.urlMain, 
          
            formData
          )
            .then( (res) => {
                console.log(res.data)
                router.push('/thanks')
                

            })
            .catch( (err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
```

By server side ? via render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data can be static so either:

- hard coded
- taken from a local `.json`, `.yml` or equivalent
- cookie/localStorage/[equivalent client-side DB/persistency]

Or if you're using a meta-framework like AstroJS or Nuxt (even tho, there will still be a fetch on the server at some point, likely at build time). But there is nothing direct like a twig template.

You can also use Vue inside of Laravel (via InertiaJS) for example. But there is no direct DB/SPA connection possible by default because Vue is not meant for such thing.